# To which level returns a return inside a Proc Object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, proc

As I understood `return` inside a `Proc` terminates the current method. So in the following example I would expect to see:
a1 > b1 > proc > a2. But actually it never reaches a2, why?

```
def a
  puts "a1"
  l = Proc.new {puts "proc"; return}
  b l
  puts "a2"
end

def b x
  puts "b1"
  x.call
  puts "b2"
end

a
```

Comment: The "Proc" uses the context from the method it was defined, so you defined it on "a" method, so you can use the "a" methods variables, and it will return the "a" method context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, `return` always returns from the *closest lexically enclosing method definition expression*.

In this case, the closest lexically enclosing method definition expression is `def a`, therefore, `return` returns from `a`.

It does not actually matter that the `return` is inside a block in this case. The general rule is, well, general, so it applies regardless of where the `return` appears.

If we look more specifically at blocks, though, we can see that it still makes sense: in blocks, local variables are captured lexically, `self` is captured lexically, so it makes sense that `return` also behaves lexically. It is a general property of blocks that if you want to understand what is going on in a block, you only need to look lexically outwards.

And if we get even more specific, first going from the general rule to blocks, and now from blocks to `Proc`s, the behavior still makes sense: a `Proc` is essentially a reified block, so it makes sense for a `Proc` to behave like a block.

There *are* some exceptions, though, to the *general rule*, and one important one are *lambdas*. Talking about lambdas in Ruby is always a little bit weird because lambdas are `Proc`s but they behave differently from `Proc`s. IMO, lambdas should have a separate class alongside `Proc`s. Since lambdas are `Proc`s, it makes it weird to talk about the differences between lambdas and `Proc`s which are not lambdas (which don't have a standardized name and thus are confusingly also called `Proc`s).

The behavior of a lambda differs from the behavior of a non-lambda `Proc` in two ways, one of which is relevant to your question:

- Parameter binding in non-lambda `Proc`s has the same semantics as parameter binding in blocks, whereas parameter binding in lambdas has the same semantics as parameter binding in message sends / method invocations.
- In non-lambda `Proc`s, `return` returns from the closest lexically enclosing method definition expression, just like in blocks, whereas in lambdas, `return` returns from the lambda itself, just like `return` in methods.

So, in both of these aspects, non-lambda `Proc`s behave like blocks and lambdas behave like methods. I memorize it like this: "`Proc`" rhymes with "block" and both "lambda" and "method" are Greek.

As you probably know, there are some methods which also alter the behavior of blocks that are passed to them. E.g. `instance_eval` and `instance_exec` change the value of `self`, and `define_method` actually does change the behavior of `return`.

But since you didn't ask about blocks in general, and also didn't ask about lambdas specifically, and there are no reflective methods in your question, the general rules still applies to non-lambda `Proc`s like the one shown in your question: `return` returns from the closest lexically enclosing method definition expression.

Comment: I am not sure if I get this right. If I define a Proc Block containing a return at main level and send it to a method, which is the nearest method definition?

Comment: Did you try it? There is no enclosing method definition, hence you will get a `LocalJumpError`.

Comment: Ah, OK - now I see my mistake. The execution inside the atom editor shows a different behaviour than in plain ruby. In Atom there is no Exception raised.